# ¿ DAO/VO Personalizado?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mvc, patrones-de-diseño

Buena noche, estoy realizando un proyecto con conexiona a MySQL, estoy utilizando los patrones de diseño: MVC, DAO/VO.

Tengo en mi base de datos varias tablas, 11 en total, por lo cual tengo 11 VO y 11 DAO, con los cuales realizo mis consultas y guardo la información de ellas, ahora bien, en una de las vistas necesito mostrar cierta información que une dos tablas, necesito algunos campos de la tabla X y otros campos de la tabla Y, la forma en que solucione esto fue creando un DAO/VO personalizado, en donde en el VO mapeaba los datos que necesitaba mostrar de ambas tablas, y en el DAO realizaba las consultas respectivas.

Mi pregunta en especifico es: ¿ Es correcto crear un DAO personalizado el cual no representa como tal una tabla de la Base de Datos, si no que representa la union de varias tablas segun mi necesidad. O estoy violando algun principio ?

Comment: ¿Estas usando JPA? ¿Tienes entidades en tu aplicación para hacer el mapeo relacional o solo VO?

Comment: Hola, no uso JPA, solo uso VO para mapear las tablas de mi BD (MySQL).
Una de las tablas es Cliente, cuyos campos son Cliente_ID, Cliente_Nombre, Cliente_Apellido, Cliente_Telefono, por lo cual mi VO es el siguiente:

public class Cliente {

    private int clienteId;
    private String clienteNombre;
    private String clienteApellido;
    private String clienteTelefono;    
//Constructor, Getter y Setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El patrón de diseño DAO se trata de abstraer el acceso a datos del resto de la aplicación. No importa el repositorio de datos ni la cantidad de tablas.

En Java EE es parte de los patrones considerados esenciales y lo detallan en la siguiente url:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

[image: Patron DAO]

Para la lógica de negocio de tu aplicación, lo importante no son las tablas, sino los objetos de negocio que modelan el problema que estas resolviendo.

Un solo objeto de negocio puede resultar en el almacenamiento de datos en multiples tablas.

Comment: Eso significaría que podría crear tantos VOs como DAOs personalizados como me sean necesarios, es decir, que sean la representación de la unión de las tablas que necesito llevar al sistema, y no necesariamente con la totalidad de los campos de cada tabla si no con los concretos que necesito.
PD: En las publicación como hago para darle el formato correspondiente al código ?